# Variable in coffeescript and jQuery does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coffeescript

```
datePicker = $("#datepicker")
$ ->
  $("#datepicker").datepicker()
```

The above works great, the belove does not.

```
datePicker = $("#datepicker")
$ ->
  datePicker.datepicker()
```

I cannot find a reason why the second one does not invoke the calendar control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're registering a function to run at DOM ready. In your first example, you're not looking for the `#datepicker` element until the DOM is ready; in your *second* example, you're looking for it *right away*, but then trying to use it later on DOM ready.

I expect it's failing because this code is above the `#datepicker` element in the HTML, so the element doesn't exist yet when the code runs.

If you move the code to the bottom of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag (which is generally [a good idea](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) anyway), both should work (and you can stop using the DOM ready callback).

Comment: yup, that's it. I hate javascript :)

Comment: @almendar: This has nothing to do with JavaScript. It's just that you were looking for something before it existed. It's no different than trying to read a file before it exists. Doesn't matter what language you're using, it's a logic and timing thing. :-)

Comment: Your probably right, just the whole document.ready and other stuff (e.g. 'this' keyword) is not my kind of story and keeps me confused all the time :)
Probably just a matter of experience.